# How do I change the name of an array inside of a for loop?

Tags: java

Note: I am a beginner so please be patient with me

```
public class ArrayExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array1 = {5, 7, 6, 4};
        int[] array2 = {1, 3, 1, 8};
        int[] array3 = {9, 2, 3, 5};
         
        //array of arrays
        int[][] arrays = {array1, array2, array3};
         
        for(int[] arr: arrays) {
            for(int n: arr) {
                System.out.print(n+" ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

In this example pulled from the internet, instead of hard coding array1, array2, array3, can I put it inside of a for loop and say

```
for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
{
int[]array[i] =.... 


}
```

int [][] array= {array[i]}

then print everything out?

Comment: That's not possible.

Comment: Why do you think you need to change the name of an array (variable)? What are you actually trying to achieve, and what isn't your code doing that you want it to do? Please see [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Dynamic variables are not possible in Java. If you can give a clear problem statement of what you are trying to achieve then it might help others to give a solution

Comment: You could use an array of arrays: `int[][] arrayOfArrays = new int[3][]; arrayOfArrays[0] = array1; arrayOfArray[1] = array2; arrayOfArrays[2] = array3;`

Comment: Sounds good, thank you for the feedback. I will change my logic and find a different method.

Comment: Why do you even have `array1`, `array2` and `array3`? You could instead do `int[][] arrays = { { 5, 7, 6, 4 }, { 1, 3, 1, 8 }, { 9, 2, 3, 5 } };`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot dynamically change a variable at run time since they are only available at compile time.

There are two ways to solve your problem:

1. Create an array of arrays and add an extra for loop to loop over this array of arrays.
2. Create a function to do the work and pass each array to the function. Internally, the function uses a single local variable name, but the value of that variable can be set from each array in `main()`.